# Stack around the variable 'input' was corrupted

Tags: c

I just started my C language and I came to this error. I tried to look up online but other threads contain ARRAY which I am not familiarize with.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){

    char input;
    printf("ASCII testing\n");
    scanf( "%d", &input); //the error occurs here but would like to know the solution

    printf("answer is : %c\n" , input);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'input' was corrupted."

Simple point-out will be much appreciated

//Edited

Well I would like to enter value "66" so that the outcome would be B. The scanf("%c , &input) accepts 1 keystroke from the keyboard so that's not what I am looking for. But nevertheless, thank you for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier in `scanf()` requires a pointer to an `int` variable, not a pointer to a `char`. Try:

```
int input;
scanf( "%d", &input);
```

Answer (score 6):

**The Problem**

`%d` is the format specifier for integer input, leading the compiler to assume that &input points to an integer rather than a character.

```
scanf( "%d", &input);
```

should be

```
scanf( "%c", &input);
```

**Why this corrupts the stack**

The reason for the corrupted stack is that input is allocated on the stack, and scanf assumes it occupies 4 bytes (on a 32 bit platform) rather than the 1 byte actually allocated on the stack.  As a result, other things on the stack (other variables, return address, ...) are overwritten.